# MPI_Sendrecv Freezing

Tags: c++, runtime, mpi

I'm trying to demonstrate the simplest possible use of MPI_Sendrecv that I can think of, that is to exchange integers between two MPI Processes. However when I run the following code it simply hangs on the MPI_Sendrecv call and gets no further. Can someone please help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int rank;
    int numProcesses;
    int destinationProcess;
    int sourceProcess;
    int sendInt;
    int receiveInt;
    MPI_Status status;

    const int DEFAULT_INT = -9;

    /*Start MPI environment */
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numProcesses);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    /* Abort if not exactly 2 processes */
    if(numProcesses != 2){
        std::cout << "This application is meant to be run with 2 processes." << std::endl;
        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Establish sending and receiving ranks */
    sendInt = rank;
    receiveInt = DEFAULT_INT;
    if(rank == 0){
        destinationProcess = 1;
        sourceProcess = rank;
    } else {
        destinationProcess = 0;
        sourceProcess = rank;
    }

    /* Display a message containing relevant info prior to MPI_Sendrecv call*/
    std::cout << "My rank is: " << rank << std::endl;
    std::cout << "My receiveInt is: " << receiveInt << std::endl;
    std::cout << "My sendInt is:" << sendInt << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Carrying out MPI_Sendrecv" << std::endl;

    MPI_Sendrecv(&sendInt, 1, MPI_INT, destinationProcess, 0 , &receiveInt, 1, MPI_INT, sourceProcess, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

    /* Display a message containing relevant info prior to MPI_Sendrecv call*/
    std::cout <<" MPI_Sendrecv carried out." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "My receiveInt is: " << receiveInt << std::endl;
    std::cout << "My sendInt is:" << sendInt << std::endl;


    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: your program does not compile ...

Comment: you're supposed to be sending and receiving from the same process `destinationProcess`. However, your call to `MPI_Sendrecv()` sends to `destinationProcess` alright, but expects receiving from itself!

Comment: Hi Gilles, thanks for the response. I want process rank 0 to send an integer to process rank 1, and vice versa. When I added a std::cout statement before the MPI_Sendrecv call I can confirm this code does not tell the system to expect to receive from itself. I also tested swapping the sourceProcess and destinationProcess in the MPI_Sendrecv call but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: @VeryLargeDog, @Gilles is correct.  For instance, you want rank 0 to send to rank 1 _and_ receive from rank 1.  What you want is `destinationProcess=sourceProcess=!rank`.  What you have is `destinationProcess=!rank` and `sourceProcess=rank`

Comment: Gilles and @ptb thanks! That solved my problem! I set it up as per ptb's solution and it works great. It's not how I imagined it was working, this really helped me out.